# Angular view not refreshing after the array updates from $http

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I've the following code that displays table of data using ng-repeat, initially the model (array) will have no data, but upon request to an api it receives some data that i'm trying to update my model with, but unfortunately my view is not getting refreshed with model updates though I see that my model contains the new data that was received from api call.

Component code:

```
app.component('fooList', {
    bindings: {
        foo: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: '/app/foo.html',
    controllerAs: 'list',
    controller: function ($http,$scope) {
        let list=this;
        list.search=()=>{           
            $http.get('/ui/foo/'+ list.searchCriteria)
                 .success(response=>{
                     list.foo.searchResults=response.searchResults;
                 })
        }
    }
});
```

HTML View:

```
<tr ng-repeat="foo in ::list.foo.searchResults">
        <td>{{::foo.name}}</td>
        <td>{{::foo.address}}</td>
    </tr>
```

I've tried the following so far which didn't help

1. Setting the list.foo.searchResults to undefined initially, which is working fine for the first time, but if I send a different search criteria then again it is not refreshing.
2. $scope.$apply(), which I hate to do, but tried which is throwing digest in progress error.
3. Inside the success of $http i've tried the below code
   list.foo.searchResults=0;
   list.foo.searchResults.push.apply(list.foo.searchResults,response.searchResults);
4. Created one more child component and replaced my html with the child template and moved the code to populate the array in to that component.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Wondering why did u used one time data binding ? `::` ?

Comment: and also if u using arrow function no need to do `let list = this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove **one time data binding**.

```
<tr ng-repeat="foo in list.foo.searchResults">
    <td>{{foo.name}}</td>
    <td>{{foo.address}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Oh man, you saved my day. Thanks. But I still don't understand why shouldn't I use one way binding as I'm not making any changes to my model from my view.

Comment: I misspelled. It's one time data binding. According to angularjs docs:
`One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value`

Answer (score 1):

Try removing ::  or can you give a jsfiddle to work on

Answer (score 1):

`::` is used to provide one way databinding , please remove it and then try

`::`if you are using this, even if your model is getting updated it will not allow to update view.

Comment: ok, I totally misunderstood the concept of this one way binding. I was always under an impression that if there are no changes being made to the model by the view then we use ::

Answer (score 0):

You may try to update in the view section while you are fetching data from service, use **$scope.$apply()** in your controller section, where your are taking value from service(means storing in array).

or remove **::** from your html part because its give to one way binding in angularjs.